# RegEx.Replace function limits the character returned

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Lets say this sample cell data value is more than 1600+ characters. My goal is to get the value 7 as the # of test cases affected / impacted.

"6.     # of test cases affected / impacted:77.     Additional comments:If applicable, a description of the screenshot(s) attached:"

Pseudo Code:

1. Remove text with number+dot format (in this case 6. and 7.) in the string using this regex pattern **"\d[.]"**
2. Find and extract the text + the number after the string using this regex pattern **text + ".*?\d+"**
3. Extract number from the extracted text using this regex pattern **"\d+"**

Additional information :

I need to create a function that will give the user to provide a custom text in the "Find_Text" parameter. the custom text can be also be a comma delimited. so that they can reuse the function to extract a value from a specific cell or text. See example below.

"1. number of test case:30 2. number of defect:5 3. test case number:1001"

- If find_text = "number of test case:" the output is 30
- If find_text = "number of defect:" the output is 5
- If find_text = "test case number:" the output is 1001

Here's the source code:
[VBAExcelRegex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikhzc.png)

If I remove the step 1 the actual output is 77

- Step 2 value will be "impacted:77"
- Step 3 value will be "77"

If I include the step 1 the actual output is N/A that supposed to be 7

- Step 1 value will be limited to the first 255 characters
- Step 2 value will be N/A
- Step 3 value will be N/A

Source Code:

```
Private Function RegExExtract(ByVal Str As String, ByVal Pattern As String, Optional DefaultValue As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean)
Dim RegEx
Set RegEx = New RegExp
RegEx.Pattern = Pattern
RegEx.Global = True
RegEx.MultiLine = True
RegEx.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
If RegEx.Test(Str) Then
    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(Str)
    RegExExtract = Matches(0).Value
Else
    RegExExtract = DefaultValue
End If 
End Function

Private Function RegExReplace(ByVal Str As String, ByVal Pattern As String, ByVal ReplaceBy As String, Optional DefaultValue As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean)
Dim RegEx
Set RegEx = New RegExp
RegEx.Pattern = Pattern
RegEx.Global = True
RegEx.MultiLine = True
RegEx.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
If RegEx.Test(Str) Then
    RegExReplace = RegEx.Replace(Str, ReplaceBy)
Else
    RegExReplace = Str
End If
End Function

Function RegexExtractNumberAfterString(Source As Range, Find_Text As String, Optional DefaultValue As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean)
Dim a, b, c, pattern1, pattern2, pattern3
'   Replace number+dot format e.g 1. 2.
pattern3 = "\d[.]"
c = RegExReplace(Source.Value, pattern3, "", DefaultValue, IgnoreCase)
'   Loop until text is found and extract that text
Dim arrFindText() As String
arrFindText() = Split(Find_Text, ",")
Dim text As Variant
For Each text In arrFindText
    pattern1 = text + ".*?\d+"
    a = RegExExtract(c, pattern1, DefaultValue, IgnoreCase)
    If Not (a = DefaultValue Or a = "") Then Exit For
Next text
'   Extract number from the text
pattern2 = "\d+"
b = RegExExtract(a, pattern2, DefaultValue, IgnoreCase)
RegexExtractNumberAfterString = b
End Function

Sub RegEx()
 MsgBox (RegexExtractNumberAfterString(Excel.activeCell, "impacted:,test cases:", "N/A", True))
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code itself. Images make it very hard for others to experiment with the code. Who wants to type it?

Comment: Maybe just one `regex.Execute` will do with `(\d+)\..*?(\d+)?(?=\d\.|$)`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bw6Riu/1/). Then just check for `Find_Text` in each match

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you for the advice.

Comment: @GSerg thats why I need to do the step 1 from the pseudo code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have provided additional information. kindly check while Im checking the regex that you've provided. thank you.

Comment: The real problem is why Regex.Replace limits the returned characters to 255. and how to solve that.

Comment: Just tried an `Regex.Replace` on a 3000 length string and it worked perfectly. So it's not limited in that way.

Comment: @JvdV in that case, can someone tell me why I got N/A result when using RegExReplace function from the source code that I've provided?

Comment: update: if i tried to manually split and store the large text to multiple variable like this
var1 - first 255 characters
var2 - next set of characters
var3 - remaining characters
var4 = var1+var2+var3
then pass the var4 to the Regex.Replace I got the expected result. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

It get resolved when I replaced the parameter to ByRef instead of ByVal.

**Old code:** 
Private Function RegExReplace(**ByVal** Str As String, ByVal Pattern As String, **ByVal** ReplaceBy As String, Optional DefaultValue As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean)

**New code:** 
Private Function RegExReplace(Str As String, ByVal Pattern As String, ReplaceBy As String, Optional DefaultValue As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean)